# jQuery toggle list menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

When I click on the span that is within the section, the list within only that section is supposed to be toggled. What happens though is that every list within every section is toggled, not just the one that belongs to the section that I am clicking on.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="tutorial-box">
  <p>
    <a href="#">Link #1</a>
    <br />
    Some text.
    <br />
    <span class="view-contents plus-sign">Click Here</span>
  </p>

  <ul class="tutorial-box-list">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="clear"> </div> <!-- end div class clear -->
</section> <!-- end section class tutorial-box -->

<section class="tutorial-box">
  <p>
    <a href="#">Link #2</a>
    <br />
    Some more text.
    <br />
    <span class="view-contents plus-sign">Click Here</span>
  </p>

  <ul class="tutorial-box-list">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="clear"></div> <!-- end div class clear -->

</section> <!-- end section class tutorial-box -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.tutorial-box{
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tutorial-box p{
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.view-contents{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.plus-sign{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: url("../images/plus-icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.minus-sign{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: url("../images/minus-icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**jQuery / JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tutorial-box-list').hide();
  $('.view-contents').click(function() {
    if($('.tutorial-box span').hasClass('plus-sign')) {
      $('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');
      $('.tutorial-box span').addClass('minus-sign').removeClass('plus-sign');
    }
    else {
      $('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');
      $('.tutorial-box span').addClass('plus-sign').removeClass('minus-sign');
    }
  });

  $('.toggle').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.toggle-content').hide();
  });
});
```

- [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y34d4egm/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are calling this ".tutorial-box-list", it will add toggle event in all the respective classes present in the page, so you need to select from the parent class and next add the required event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code where you can use `toggleClass` to add / remove `'plus-sign` and `minus-sign` simultaneously. And use `closest` to get parent `tutorial-box` to find `tutorial-box-list` to toggle it.

```
$('.view-contents').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.tutorial-box').find('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');
      $(this).toggleClass('plus-sign minus-sign');
  });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y34d4egm/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why because you are trying to toggle class `tutorial-box-list`. You have assigned this class for both of the contents. So, The code toggled both contents at the same time.

**Just use**

`$(this).parent().next().slideToggle('2000');`

**insetead of**

`$('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');`

**Here is the** <kbd>[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y34d4egm/2/)</kbd>

Comment: This works. However how can I change image of the section that is clicked changing from a plus sign to a minus sign, they all change to a minus sign when clicked and vice versa.

Comment: @DipakG. I think `.tutorial-box span` and `.view-contents` are same selectors. So you can simply use `$(this)` instead of `$('.tutorial-box span')`. Like this `$(this).addClass('minus-sign').removeClass('plus-sign');`. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/y34d4egm/8/

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the element relative to the clicked element so

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.tutorial-box-list').hide();
    $('.view-contents').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).closest('.tutorial-box').find('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');
        $this.toggleClass('minus-sign plus-sign');
    });

    $('.toggle').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.toggle-content').hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nmgafx6o/)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies considering I'm on mobile. The issue looks like every time you use `$('.tutorial-box span')` it uses all of those elements it finds on the page. 
When you want to affect just that element, use

```
$(this)
```

And it will affect only the one that was clicked. And if you want to access the parent section use

```
$(this).closest('.tutorial-box')
```

If you'd like I can spin up my laptop and create a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this click event

```
$('.view-contents').click(function() {
      var section = $(this).closest('section');
      var sectionSpan =section.find('.tutorial-box span');
      var sectionList = section.find('.tutorial-box-list');
    if(sectionSpan.hasClass('plus-sign')) {
     sectionList.slideToggle('2000');
     sectionSpan.addClass('minus-sign').removeClass('plus-sign');
    }
    else {
      sectionList.slideToggle('2000');
     sectionSpan.addClass('plus-sign').removeClass('minus-sign');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update ur js

```
jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tutorial-box-list').hide();
  $('.view-contents').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('plus-sign')) {
      $(this).closest('.tutorial-box').find('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');
      $(this).addClass('minus-sign').removeClass('plus-sign');
    }
    else {
      $(this).closest('.tutorial-box').find('.tutorial-box-list').slideToggle('2000');
      $(this).addClass('plus-sign').removeClass('minus-sign');
    }
  });

});
```